# dynamic params for ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on an Ember project in which I have to specify the parameters of the component dynamically.

I have the following array in the .js controller:

```
componentParams: ["id", "name"]
```

What I want to do is to take the values in the array and use them in handlebars as the component parameter like this

```
{{component-name id=somevalue name="somevalue"}}
```

Could this be done?

Comment: So you would like to dynamically define the attrs that are passed into the component? Eg. if `componentParams: ['foo', 'bar']` then `{{component-name foo='va1' bar='val2'`?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i want, do you have any idea?

Comment: It depends, are you stuck with that array, how does that array get populated ?? `componentParams: ["id", "name"]` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I use.

*controller.js*

```
navbarParams: {
   titleToShow: 'General.ResearchProjects',
   glyphicon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-globe',
   infoText: 'information/project'
},
```

*template.hbs*

```
{{my-navbar params=navbarParams}}
```

*my-navbar.hbs*

```
<h1> {{params.titleToShow}} <span class={{params.glyphicon}}> </span> </h1>
```

If your parameters are queryParams

They should be defined like that

```
queryParams: ['foo', 'bar',],
foo: null,
bar: null

{{my-navbar first=foo second=bar}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it depends, if you are stuck with that array - you can use computed properties to extract the proper array values. ( This is probably not recommended - a better approach would be to format your `componentParams` into an object ( like @kristjan's example).

If you are stuck with the array - and the positions will never change ( id will always be `componentParams[0]` & name will always be `componentParams[1]`, you could try something like this ::

```
// controller
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  Controller,
  computed,
  get
} = Ember;

export default Controller.extend({
  componentParams: ['id', 'name'],
    componentName: computed('componentParams', {
    get() {
        return get(this, 'componentParams')[1];
    }
  }),
  componentId: computed('componentParams', {
    get() {
        return get(this, 'componentParams')[0]; 
    }
  })
});


// template
{{my-component name=componentName id=componentId}}

// component/template
name:: {{name}}
<br>
id :: {{id}}
```

[check out this twiddle for a working example](https://ember-twiddle.com/a28d215654a392b8c75ad962136a70b6?fileTreeShown=false&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

Does this help ??